# Web API Routing and query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I was playing around with Web API and MVC routing.  I noticed something that I think is odd.  When you use the route attribute the framework is less forgiving.  You will notice that the Get method in the first section fails when the id is a path and that it must be part of the query string.  However in the second section it picks up the id as either one.  I would have thought that the code in the first section would have behaved like the code in the second section.  It is my understanding that the MVC framework will try and route the traffic, picking up the value from the query string if it has to, which is what the second section of code is doing.  Apparently when you use the route attribute it doesn’t do that. Can somebody explain?

**---------------------First section (code with Route attribute)**

*WebApiConfig.cs*

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefualtRouting", 
                               "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                               new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

*TestController.cs*

```
[Route("api/test/")] //(notice routing attribute)
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Here is what I get when I target these URL's

- localhost:43321/api/Test/1 -this returns a 404
- localhost:43321/api/Test?id=1 – this works

**---------------------second section (code without Route attribute)**
*WebApiConfig.cs*

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefualtRouting", 
                               "api/{controller}/{id}", 
                               new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

*TestController.cs*

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Here is what I get when I target these URL's

- localhost:43321/api/Test/1 - this works
- localhost:43321/api/Test?id=1 – this works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm confused.  But your attribute should look like this:

```
[Route("api/test/{id}")] //(notice routing attribute)
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

It also looks like you're using attribute routing AND configuring routes in WebApiConfig.cs.  Or is that just your fallback?

I only use one or the other.

If you're trying to make the id optional, I think you can do this:

```
[Route("api/test/{id:string?}")] //(notice routing attribute)
public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

For reference, see:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional

Comment: Web API and MVC are fairly new to me.  I was going through a pluralsight tutorial that was using the routing attribute and the configuration routing, why he did this I don't know for sure.  One of the questions that I am trying to get answered here is why does the controller with the route attribute not pick up the ID from the query string when the controller without the route attribute does.

Comment: Because the one without the route attribute defines the Id as optional.  My example shows how to do that with the attribute.